# Laravel eloquent update column value by adding new value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using updateOrCreate() method to update points of current user:

```
   $point->updateOrCreate(
        ['user_id' => auth()->id()],
        ['score' => request('totalScore')]
    );
```

If `request('totalScore')` is  50, and current value of column `score` is 10, I want to `update` it to 60. But as you can see, the above-mentioned approach directly replaces 10 with 50.

Google search returned results containing query builder's increment() method. But I didn't have to use the query builder in my entire application. Why should I use it now? Would it be possible to update the value using the Eloquent methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these methods in your Eloquent queries."
>
> [Laravel 5.5 Docs - Eloquent - Retrieving Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models)

You can use Eloquent to use any of the Query Builder methods or any Eloquent specific methods.

Comment: well `updateOrCreate` returns a model, not a builder, but if you want to then increment a field on that model instance it has its own `increment` method you can call

Comment: Got it. I am updating your answer. Please let me know if I've done something wrong.

Comment: Getting this error when I try this with a new user id:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'score' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `points` (`user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (5, 2017-12-06 19:38:07, 2017-12-06 19:38:07))
```

Comment: the schema you designed says it needs a value .. then you need to give it a value or set some default

Comment: Just tested in every possible way, I can assure you that value of score is being passed properly. The statement should have created a new row with the new user_id, or should have updated the score column if the row with current user_id was already found...

Comment: @Eisenheim sorry but you are mistaken ... you are not passing `score` at all when it is created

Comment: I was referring to passing the variable to the controller's `update()` method. I understand that score is not being passed through `updateOrCreate`. I just don't know how to tackle the situation. Because If I now pass a score as the 2nd arg, it will double the value of score due to the chained increment method.

Comment: don't use `updateOrCreate` ... do it yourself ... there is no reason to try and force a square peg into a round hole

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160656/discussion-between-eisenheim-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer had a problem (see comments). So I had to come up with another solution. I created a [local query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) called `updateOrCreateAndIncrement()` in my model:

```
public function scopeUpdateOrCreateAndIncrement($query, $totalScore){
        if(!$query->where('user_id',auth()->id())->first()){
            $query->create(['user_id' => auth()->id(), 'score' => $totalScore]);
        } else {
            $query->where('user_id',auth()->id())->increment('score', $totalScore);
        }
    }
```

And in the controllers `update()` method, I can easily call `$point->updateOrCreateAndIncrement()`:

```
public function update(Request $request, Points $point){
    $point->updateOrCreateAndIncrement(request('totalScore'));
}
```

Comment: it isn't a scope in reality (as they are for adding constraints to queries as builders)... just create a regular method on your model   or macro onto `Eloquent\Builder`

Comment: As a side note, what are some other things, apart from queries, that I can create a macro on?

Comment: I have a small list near the bottom:  https://asklagbox.com/blog/laravel-macros  ... which is incomplete as I am sure more classes have this functionality now as of 5.5